# Filtering a group of entities using AngularJS (DropDownList + Grid working together). Using WEBAPI/MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I know how to populate and grid with the data I want and I know how to populate the dropdownlist with the data I want. Now I want to have the grid react to the dropdownlist. I mean it is a typical filter scenario. In this case I have different 'Congresses' (the dropdownlist) and depending on which dropdown item is selected it should get the appropriate collection of 'Congress Members'.. So the two main questions are...

1. How do I make the grid check the dropdownvalue for the filter value and then call the REST service? I need the call to fill the grid data AFTER the call to fill the dropdownlist.
2. How do I use Webapi for this? How do I create a restful interface for "Give me the 112th Congress Members" ? It does not seem to fit in the REST standards interface. My best guess is I should not use the built in REST endpoints that match the Entities but create a Custom one ?? Something like /api/CustomCongressFiles/112  ?

```
    appRoot.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $location, $resource) {

    var ccResource = $resource('/api/CongressCongresses/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
    var userResource = $resource('/api/CongressMember', {}, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });

    $scope.usersList = [];
    $scope.ccList = [];

    // userResource.get({ CongressMember: 100 }, function () {
     userResource.query(function (data) {
        $scope.usersList.length = 0;
        angular.forEach(data, function (userData) {
            $scope.usersList.push(userData);
        })
    });

    ccResource.query(function (data) {
        $scope.ccList.length = 0;
        angular.forEach(data, function (ccData) {
            $scope.ccList.push(ccData);
        })

        $scope.lastItem = $scope.ccList[$scope.ccList.length - 1];
    });


    $scope.userGrid = {
        data: 'usersList',
        multiSelect: false,
        selectedItems: $scope.selectedUsers,
        enableColumnResize: false,
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'firstname', displayName: 'First Name', width: '25%' },
            { field: 'lastname', displayName: 'Last Name', width: '25%' }
        ]
    };
});
```

```
<div class="row">
<div>
    <select ng-model="lastItem" ng-options="cc.congressLongName for cc in ccList"></select>
</div>
<div class="grid-style" data-ng-grid="userGrid">
</div>
```

```
  public class CongressMemberController : ApiController
{
    private CongressDb_DevEntities db = new CongressDb_DevEntities();

    // GET api/CongressMember
    public IQueryable<tMember> GettMembers()
    {
        return db.tMembers.Where(x => x.MembersID < 100);
    }

    // GET api/CongressMember/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(tMember))]
    public IHttpActionResult GettMember(int id)
    {
        tMember tmember = db.tMembers.Find(id);
        if (tmember == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(tmember);
    }
```

Comment: if grid has watch for change of data array, using `ng-change` on `<select>` you could make request and update data, or use `$watch` to do it. Internal Watch on data would then rebuild grid. Read API docs for grid. As for API..last comment in question 2 makes sense

Comment: So I would not need to deal with embedding one call inside another in javascript ? I can have the grid somehow wait for a signal before making the rest call? Where can I get more basic information about this ?

Comment: not sure whay you need nested calls...simply because I can't see what you are loading in first place. If need another call after first, chain promises together

Comment: Do you already have enough data to filter if user changes select?  Just not clear what overall issues are

Comment: I thought with javascript because the calls are async you need to wait for one call to end beforfe starting the other so you would put the 2nd call in the callback of the 1st.. that make sense?  I am coming from simple c# and just calling one command after another

Comment: depends on whether one call is dependent on data from another or not. Can make multiple calls simultaneously and push into promise array so data can be manipulated once all calls are complete also. Nesting calls is not uncommon either.

Comment: The grid needs to know the value of the dropdownlist. On the initial load I will set the dropdownlist value. After that I want the grid to react to user changes of the dropdownlist. You have any resource you can point me to help me understand what concepts I should know ?

Comment: depsnd on grid, will it update if it's data source changes? If so, when you change the select would filter your data and change the data source for grid. Keep copy of oirginal data so it stays intact

Comment: hate to say this but sounds like you need deeper understanding of how angular works, and protoypical inheritance. Likely best to dig through any wiki, github resources etc for grid

Comment: I totally agree. Jumping into javascript/angular after just doing c#.net has some surprises. Mostly understanding how to call functions on the server and get data back

Comment: if new to javascript...angular is not for you..yet. Requires some deeper fundamentals than using libraries like jQuery